# Collision between 2D circle and flat surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, simulations

First of all I want to preface this post by saying that I am absolutely terrible at maths, my level of geometry equals being able to discern a circle from a rectangle but that's about it, as for trigonometry I know nil.

I'm making a [Pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) game, and I have coded everything but the collision logic and also of course calculation of ball velocity and trajectory based on the angle of the ball.

The problem right now is that I just don't know how to proceed now, I realize that I have to do some kind of trigonometry to modify the angle of the ball upon impact, but it would be great if someone could point me in a more specific direction because trigonometry is a pretty big and vast field.. Also keeping in mind that my math skills are.. Quite basic..

Comment: You probably just need angle of incidence equals angle of reflection, right?

Comment: Someone mentioned that to me earlier, but I got the impression that angle of incidence had something to do with light and/or other rays reflecting on a surface, not physical objects. But I guess I got it wrong.

Comment: It does have to do with light rays, but try to think of a ball bouncing off a surface. In the absence of gravity, how does it bounce? The case of 90 degrees and 0 degrees (with respect to the surface) are an easy way to get started.

Comment: Try here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23672/  gamedev.SE is very useful for physics questions too!

Comment: If you could tell us how you are controlling the ball, we can help using relevant terms.

Comment: Note that the actual pong game _does not_ follow the laws of physics as far as the paddle/ball interaction go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is belongs to [Gamedev.SE] as it is about coding a game and not the laws of physics,

Comment: Are you considering the rotation of the ball and/or friction in the contact interface? Otherwise the paddle would behave just like a wall. Also what do you _want_ the game to do when you hit the end of the paddle?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your ball's motion is based on an X and Y velocity. In circle-vertical/horizontal collisions, it's pretty simple maths.
When the ball hits either paddle (Vertical) the Y velocity remains constant, and the X will switch signs. When the ball hits either top or bottom (Horizontal) the X velocity remains constant, and the Y will switch signs.

Comment: The answer would be improved by actually showing the computations.